Publish Artifact in Azure Devops Pipeline : Getting Permission to Path Denied Error
This is my Yaml Pipeline Script
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/DockerImage.tar'
    ArtifactName: 'Docker-Image'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

This is the Error Logs

Fail to upload '/home/vsts/work/1/a/DockerImage.tar' due to 'Access to the path '/home/vsts/work/1/a/DockerImage.tar' is denied.'.
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/home/vsts/work/1/a/DockerImage.tar' is denied.
---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func2 errorRewriter) at Interop.CheckIo(Error error, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func2 errorRewriter)
at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode)
at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Build.FileContainerServer.UploadAsync(IAsyncCommandContext context, Int32 uploaderId, CancellationToken token) in /mnt/vss/_work/1/s/src/Agent.Worker/Build/FileContainerServer.cs:line 251

I tried Looking for how to give permission to my pipeline i was also using the
Pipeline.workspace location to publish my artifacts but there also i got the same error.
I am not sure how to give permission to my pipeline.
I am relatively new to Azure Devops platform.

Are you using Microsoft-hosted or self-hosted build agents? Can you share the code that generates the .tar file?

I am using the Microsoft-hosted agent.
Code  :
- script: |           sudo docker save $(AccountId).dkr.ecr.${AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com/dev:build-v1 -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/DockerImage.tar       displayName: Docker Save Command 

Hi @SanskarArya, Have you got a chance to check the answer by Rui below not to use sudo to run docker save? Hope it helps to resolve your issue in this topic. Thx.

Yes , This issue got resolved it was actually the same issue that Rui explained below, since I was using the sudo command , the permissions  in the file was for root user only and hence the pipeline was not able to get the read write priv. For the command to work. Thanks

Your issue is that you are using sudo to save the file, which saves it under a different user context than the currently executing pipeline. The pipeline agent should have sufficient permissions on the agent to do everything you need. Running 'sudo' should not be necessary.
The following works:
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: |
    docker pull busybox
    docker save busybox -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/DockerImage.tar
  displayName: Docker Save Command
  
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/DockerImage.tar'
    ArtifactName: 'Docker-Image'


Thanks for the explaination the issue is resolved now . It was the same thing that you pointed out about using the sudo command.
